# Выделить записи за последние 100 дней, а более старые удалить

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Такой вопрос, есть проект написанный на Laravel 5.4. Есть посты разделенные по дням, в одном дне примерно 30-50 постов. Суть в том что нужно сделать так, чтобы при добавлении первого поста в новый день, система чистила все посты последнего дня. То есть к примеру в начале 14 сентября 34 поста, мы добавляем посты до лимита, который наступает допустим 25 марта ( дни могут пропускаться, считаем именно те дни в которые добавлены посты ), когда мы добавляем 26 марта новый пост, все посты 14 сентября удаляются. Может не совсем понятно, но суть такова.

Если бы делал на MySQL то все в принципе понятно, ищем даты, используем модификатор уникальности, получаем 100 дат, берем крайнюю, и чистим все посты по этой дате. Но не хотелось бы уходить за рамки фреймворка, который я знаю не очень хорошо, так что подскажите пожалуйста внутренние функции которые могли бы помочь в решении моей проблемы.

Заранее спасибо )

Comment: В таблице есть поля `created_at` и `updated_at`? Если есть, то вот тебе даты

Comment: @МаксимК, так я же не поля ищу, я говорю про запросы в БД. Да, те поля там есть, и по полю created_at можно сделать запрос, с модификатором уникальности, получить 100 дат, отсортировать, убрать последнюю. Как сделать через SQL я знаю, вот только не буду же я писать query запрос через mysqli_connect, я хочу понять какие функции Laravel мне нужно использовать.

Comment: А дальше можно сделать различными вариантами. Лично мне нравится подход с обсерверами моделей, сейчас постараюсь подробней описать

Comment: Почитай перевод документации http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/queries.

Answer (score 2):

Предположим, что логика расположена в контроллере модели поста `Post`.
Тогда в методе добавления нового поста Пропишем такой код

```
// удалить записи одним запросом 
// (при этом не будет на моделях вызвано никаких событий
Post::where('created_at','<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(-100))->delete();

// второй вариант - получить записи из таблицы 
// получить все записи старше 100 дней
$cleanPosts = Post::where('created_at','<', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(-100))->get();

// и с каждой записью провести удаление, или "перемещение в корзину"
$cleanPosts->each(function(Post $post){
    $post->delete(); //обычное удаление
    $post->forceDelete(); //обычное удаление
});
```

Comment: За ответ спасибо, но ты немного неправильно понял. Не 100 дней назад от сегодняшнего. Сегодня могут быть посты, завтра нет. Следующий пост может быть в среду. Итого два дня. Не неделя. То есть нужен не диапазон дней от сегодняшнего и назад, а именно те дни в которых есть посты.

Comment: То есть алгоритм такой. Нужно сначала найти все уникальные даты. Потом исходя из их количества, проанализировать превышен ли лимит. Потом найти последнюю, и удалить все посты по последней.

Comment: сейчас попытаюсь найти код